# How can I use cmd to produce a new cmd window with certain commands already having been ran inside it?

Tags: windows, command-line, parameters, child-process

The question line is actually pretty descriptive. So I'll just be brief here.

I want to use cmd to produce a fresh cmd window that has the @echo off and cls commands already run in it. How can I accomplish this?

My thinking is not constrained to particular method either, I'm interested to see solutions I wouldn't have thought to think of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To turn echo off and run some commands the easiest is to specify another batch file to run. You can also specify multiple commands inline (Second example)

```
cmd.exe /q /k yourinitialization.bat
cmd.exe /q /k "dir & cls"
```